# Keep losing the database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a long PHP script (lasting maybe 10 minutes and involving a lot of curl calls) that I run either as as Cron job or directly. I'm using the $wpdb global variable to make SQL calls and I keep losing the mysql database with the "WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away" error.

I've tried what others suggest by changing the wait_timeout value to 3600 in wp-db.php, but it is still the same. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Never had this problem my guess would also be that you get a time out from PHP. If a time out is not the problem this may help. Create a persistent connection with your database (http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php). I have never tried it but perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Stating the obvious, this means MySQL closed the connection, either because
 - you send a query bigger than `max_allowed_packet`, or 
 - you took longer than `wait_timeout` between queries.

Assuming it is the timeout,

Put the `$wpdb->query("set wait_timeout = 1200")` near the start of your script - that saves you modifying WP core files.

If that still doesn't work, try MySQL's 'ping' function.  In `wp-includes/wp-db.php`, find `function query(`, and a little under that is the line with `mysql_query` - above that, add the line

```
mysql_ping( $dbh );
```

Ping checks the connection and tries to reconnect - I've found it very useful in long-running scripts.

Hopefully something in that will (a) make sense and (b) work for you.  And for the benefit of others reading this, don't forget that upgrading Wordpress will overwrite any changes you make to core files.

Links: http://blog.webyog.com/2009/09/02/%E2%80%9Cmysql-server-has-gone-away%E2%80%9D-part-2-session-timeout/ and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I did all that and I still have the same problem with the MySQL database being lost during those long CRON jobs